# no memory error, failed to allocate memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm new in Ruby On Rails but each time I make a mistake (in a function for instance), my computer (xubuntu 10.10) totally freezes.

Actually I can't do anything except waiting and I finally got an "No memory error -> failed to allocate memory" error after 5 or 10 minutes.

I use rails 3 and mongoDB.

I'm developping from an existing project with many gems, is there any consequences ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Possible diagnosis:

- you are using Ruby installed from ubuntu packages
- you have bad physical ram

These days it's good practice to install your rubies through RVM: http://beginrescueend.com/

If you want to test if you RAM is bad try memtest86: http://www.memtest86.com/

I'd go with installing RVM.

Comment: I've just tested the RAM -> OK I've removed completely ruby and rails from xubuntu and I've followed your RVM tuto -> OK

But it's exactly the same, my project on localhost is extremely slow...

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your Ruby version
2. Run **memtest** to perform hardware memory test

Comment: did you have a chance to run **memtest**? Ubuntu has it by default in menu bootlist