# In paperclip 3.0.4, uploading files more than 512 mb show ERROR NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an application paperclip with paperclip 3.0.4 gem and I am using a webrick server.
I am using sqlite3 database.
When I try to upload files more than 512 mb, I get an error-ERROR NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory in my command prompt. I use google chrome for seeing the output and I use Windows 7 platform.
Please I need help with as I need to upload files more than 1GB.
What changes do I need to make?

Comment: Could you write your system specs? interested more in RAM memory, I remember having a similar issue when I deployed my first app to a VPS with a low RAM, and it worked well except when I want it to load more then 10 files I had similar error, VPS support advised me to update the VPS plan to have more RAM, we did so and it worked. By the way, we also used Paperclip.

Comment: I am using 4 gb of ram on windows 7....but when I uploaded a single file of around 700mb, I got this error

Comment: A lot of answers leads to memory (RAM) issue, or ruby build, one of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733814/no-memory-error-failed-to-allocate-memory  Except the hardware I can't think of anything more that could cause this problem.